# How to get a specific value from JSON site and put on Label?

Tags: json, vb.net, label

I'm trying to put the "**last**" value of the "**USDT_BTC**" of a JSON inside a label...

**CODE**

```
    Dim BitcoinPrice As String = ""

    Dim json = New IO.StreamReader(DirectCast(DirectCast(Net.WebRequest.Create("https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker"), Net.HttpWebRequest).GetResponse, Net.HttpWebResponse).GetResponseStream)
    Dim rq As Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json.ReadToEnd)

    BitCoinPrice = $"{rq.SelectToken("USDT_BTC")}" 'and value of "last"

    Label1.Text = BitCoinPrice
```

**SITE**

```
https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker
```

**JSON Example**

```
"BTC_XRP":{"id":117,"last":"0.00001990"},
"USDT_BTC":{"id":121,"last":"11714.68222119"}, ' "last" Value
"USDT_DASH":{"id":122,"last":"736.33990743"},
```

Comment: Look at your JSON block (which is incomplete - there is much more info than you show).  `rq.SelectToken` is going to select ALL THE DATA in the USDT_BTC set `{....to...}`.  The debugger should be showing this very clearly.  So the next step is to fetch the value for `last`.  That will be a JValue so be sure to convert

Comment: How to fetch the value for "last" and convert?

Comment: 521,000 Google results for `json parse vb.net` A wealth of information is at your fingertips - literally - go forth and Google.  Read. Learn.  Profit!

Answer (score 0):

A guy on Facebook Group really interested in helping told me that the solution is to just put the value of the `"last"` after the `"USDT_BTC"`.

**Something like this:**

```
BitCoinPrice = $"{rq.SelectToken("USDT_BTC")("last")}"
```